# Is there any pure Perl module to create images and to place text in the image?

Tags: perl, image

I am looking for the pure Perl module for creation of the image file. I went through internet and found some modules GD, Imager, Prima-1.28 but these are all contains 'C' (.c) file and (.h) files.

Comment: Why is it bothering you that they contain .c and .h files? You can add a comment to your own question to answer

Comment: Why would you want a pure Perl version? And why would anyone want to spend their time not using the excellent image libraries that already exist. When you don't find something, like a pure Perl version, there's a reason for that. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any such module and I doubt that there's much demand for a pure-Perl image lib, given that a) C image libs are widely available and b) image manipulation requires you to do a lot of low-level bit twiddling of just the sort that Perl really isn't all that good at, so it would be much slower than any of the standard C image libs.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at PostScript::Simple. But I think you really want one of the XS modules.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe PerlMagick (ImageMagick) is what you are looking for?

Comment: ImageMagick has a large XS component (i.e. C files). However the OP has not explained why this is a valid constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a pure Perl module for image handling but by installing [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) you'll be able to use PerlMagick which will allow you to do everything you ever wanted.